# In Brent Week's Lightbringer, what are the alternate names for the Luxins

Tags: names, lightbringer

In Brent Weeks Lightbringer series.
(So far, The Black Prism, and the Blinding Knife)
There are alternate names for the Luxins of various colours.
Names used more informally.
I'm not actually sure if they have all been used.

So far the ones I can recall are:

- Superviolet - spidersilk
- Blue - ?
- Green - ?
- Yellow - Brightwater / Solid Brightwater
- Orange - ?
- Red - Pyre gel
- Subred - Fire Crystals.

Bonus points:

- Chi - ?
- Paryl - also spidersilk?
- Black - Obsidian/Hellstone (for "dead" black luxin_
- White - ?

I'm not certain on the spacing of the names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Appendix of "The Blinding Knife"

> ### COLLOQUIAL TERMS
>
> Students at the Chromeria are encouraged to use the proper names for
>   each color, but the impetus to name seems unstoppable. In some cases,
>   the names are used technically: pyrejelly is a thicker, longer-burning
>   draft of red that will burn long enough to reduce a body to ash. In
>   other cases, the reference becomes precisely the opposite of the
>   technical definition: brightwater was first a name for liquid yellow
>   luxin, but Brightwater Wall is solid yellow luxin.
>
> A few of the more common colloquialisms:
>
> **Sub-red:** Firecrystal
>
> **Red:** Pyrejelly, burnglue
>
> **Orange:** Noranjell
>
> **Yellow:** Brightwater
>
> **Green:** Godswood
>
> **Blue:** Frostglass, glass
>
> **Superviolet:** Skystring, soulstring, spidersilk
>
> **Black:** Hellstone, nullstone, nightfiber, cinderstone, hadon
>
> **White:** Truebright, starsblood, anachrome, luciton

Comment: Brightwater Wall has a solid yellow luxin outer layer, but there is an inner liquid layer of Brightwater to help refresh the structure. Great answer though. Oh, and this is a quote from the appendix. Weird.

Comment: Paryl is also called spidersilk. Chi is called "the revealer".